# Different types of transitions on the same slider in bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com) for a very simple slider and would like to have different types of transition between slides. For instance the first slide will move in horizontal direction while the next in vertical. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                pause: 70,
                speed: 700,
                pager: false,
                controls: false,
                mode: 'vertical',
                onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                    if (newIndex == 2)
                        this.mode = 'horizontal';
                    if (newIndex == 4)
                        this.mode = 'vertical';
                }

          });
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried ... code we can see from attempts that would let us know what direction to go when attempting to answer the question?

Comment: @rfornal I have updated with the code I tried.

Comment: I suspect that the transition you select on init has an impact on the DOM structure and CSS that gets applied, making it difficult to change on the fly.